# read data from rds mysql in sagemaker

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

Im new in AWS world. I have a rds mysql database. And i wanna read data from this db in sagemaker, but there is a problem.
Actually on local I can read this data like this:

```py
def readFromAWS():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='MY-ENDPOINT', port=3306, user='MY-USERNAME', password='MY-PASSWORD', db='DB-NAME')

    sqlText = """SELECT * FROM DB-NAME.XXX order by ID"""

    df = pd.read_sql(sqlText, conn)
    conn.close()
    return df
df=readFromAWS()
```

And on local it works well. But in sagemaker this code is useless.
I need some advice. Are there any other way to read this? Should i use other services to read this data in sagemaker? Can you give me some advice??

Comment: Why is it useless? What kind of error do you face? Common errors can be due to connection. Maybe the subnet is not correct, maybe it can't connect to the host.

Comment: Which SageMaket part are you using? Do you use a notebook instance or a sagemaker studio

Answer (score 0):

With SageMaker you can read directly data from Amazon S3, Amazon EFS or Amazon FSx for Lustre. You could import the data to S3 or try [aws-data-wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) which allows easy intergration with PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLServer etc. Here is an [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/main/tutorials/007%20-%20Redshift%2C%20MySQL%2C%20PostgreSQL%2C%20SQL%20Server.ipynb)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31769748)